# How to use conditional formatting to turn dates either red, green or yellow

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

[image]

Cell `A1` contains a date. I am trying to turn cell `A1` either red if this date is within 3 months or closer to today's date, yellow if between 3 and 6 months and if further away than 6 months, green.

What are the three formulas I should be using when trying to conditionally format this? I have attempted to read guides on this but I just can't get my head around it and I am wasting too much time trying to figure this out.

If someone could show me that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 3 conditional formatting rules for that.
Go to Conditional Formatting - New rule - Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

1. In the formula field please enter

`=A1>DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+6, DAY(TODAY()))`

In Format field below pick a green color. Then Ok.

2. New Rule with a formula

`=AND(A1<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+6, DAY(TODAY())),A1>DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+3, DAY(TODAY())))`

Add yellow color for that.

3. finally, for the closest dates you enter

`=A1<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+3, DAY(TODAY()))`

and use a red color for that.

Then click OK and that's it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have just copied and pasted those formulas, however it simply turns all dates red?

Comment: Please refresh the page and try again. I edited the answer, I think I misplaced the signs at first somehow, sorry @Excelnewman You can use 'Edit rule' not to create all the rules again. Now it should work.

Comment: I have tried this although it still only produces red results? I will edit and post a screen shot in the question

Comment: @Excelnewman I got it. I thought from your question that we're talking about the past, and now I can see that it's about the future dates, right? So give me 3 min to edit the answer, I'll change the formulas a bit.

Comment: @Excelnewman now should be good! Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use **conditional formatting** on tab **home**

[image]